# Sorting vectors based on length in C

Tags: c, vector

I want to make a programm that takes the dimension and numbers of vectors to be sorted based on their length. 
Most of the code works but the sort part of the program doesnt. 
Basically what I want to do there is: compare the output from the bereken_lengte function from 2 places in the array w. But nothing seems to happen. 
Also in the function bereken_lengte, I cant take the roots of the sum after the loop ended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double bereken_lengte(double *array, int dim)
{
  int i, j;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(i=0; i<dim; ++i)
    sum += pow(array[i],2);
  return sum;
}

void swap(double **p, double **q)
{
  double *tmp;
  tmp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = tmp;
}

void sort_vector(double *w[] , int num , int dik )
{
  int i,dim,j;
  dim = dik;
  for(i=0;i<num;++i)
    for(j = 1+i;j<num;++j)
    {
      if(bereken_lengte(w[i],dim) > bereken_lengte(w[j],dim)  )
        swap(&w[i], &w[j]);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
  int dim, num;
  int i, j,k,l;
  double **w;
  scanf ("%d %d", &dim, &num);          /* read N and M */
  w = calloc (num, sizeof (double *));  /* allocate array of M pointers */
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    /* allocate space for N dimensional vector */
    w[i] = calloc (dim, sizeof (double));
    /* read the vector */
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      scanf ("%lf", &w[i][j]);
    }
  }
  sort_vector(w,num,dim);
  for(k=0; k<num; ++k)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(l=0; l<dim; ++l)
      printf("%f ", w[k][l]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to write a sorting function, or do you just want the data to be sorted?  If you just want the data to be sorted, I would recommend calling the library function `qsort()`.

Comment: Initialise sum before adding stuff to it. sort_vector would idd be better of with qsort() instead of the dreaded bubblesort.

Comment: I don't know how many of these you're sorting, but if the number gets even remotely sizable you should consider a temp-vector of structs approach that has the `bereken_lengte()` computed **once** for each vector, and uses the precomputed value side-by-side in the struct with the array pointer as the sort-value entity. Couple that with a `qsort()`-based solution and you're performance will probably surprise you, especially for datasets of thousands of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double bereken_lengte(double *array, int dim)
{
  unsigned int i;
  double sum =0.0;
  for(i=0; i<dim; ++i)
    sum += pow(array[i],2);
  return sum;
}
```

Just initialise the sum to zero before summing.

BTW I changed i to unsigned. It is IMnsvHO a good habit to use unsigned types for index && size variables (they won't underflow, and if the do, you'll notice it)

UPDATE:
This tries to avoid the int indices and sized, and uses qsort. (rather ugly, because the compare function takes only two elements; don't try this in a multithreaded program ...) Note, I may have rows and columns interchanged, but thats a way of life... gewoon, omdat het kan!:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double bereken_lengte(double *array, size_t dim)
{
  size_t i;
  double sum=0.0;
  for(i=0; i<dim; ++i)
    sum += pow(array[i],2);
  return sum;
}

        /* this is ugly: qsort only allows only two arguments */
static size_t ze_third_argument=0;
int srt_pdbl(void *l, void *r)
{
double **dl = l, **dr = r;
double diff;
diff = bereken_lengte( *dl, ze_third_argument) - bereken_lengte( *dr, ze_third_argument) ;
return (int) diff;
}

void sort_vector(double *w[] , size_t num , size_t dik )
{
ze_third_argument = dik;
qsort(w, num, sizeof *w, srt_pdbl );
}

int main (void)
{
  size_t dim, num;
  size_t i, j,k,l;
  double **w;
  scanf ("%zu %zu", &dim, &num);          /* read N and M */
  w = calloc (num, sizeof *w);  /* allocate array of M pointers */
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    /* allocate space for N dimensional vector */
    w[i] = calloc (dim, sizeof *w[i] );
    /* read the vector */
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      scanf ("%lf", &w[i][j]);
    }
  }
  sort_vector(w,num,dim);
  for(k=0; k<num; ++k)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(l=0; l<dim; ++l)
      printf("%f ", w[k][l]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed my code with initialising sum  and my code works as expected. It was just somethin i overlooked. Thank you. The reason why i am not using sort() is because i cannot use it (school)

Comment: @user1933355 even if not using `qsort()`, you should precompute the `bereken_lengte()` of each vector *once*, store it and the associated vector pointer in a struct (two fields), and sort a vector of those structs. As it is now, there is a guaranteed minimum (n(n-1)/2) invokes you're doing now (bubble sort) and calculating two `bereken_lengte()` values per eval, almost all of them needlessly repeated, will weigh heavy on your performance.

Comment: @user1933355 : qsort is very ugly in this case. The comment about bereken_lengte() is appropiate. You recompute it on every comparison, so (for a vierkante matrix) your algorith will turn into N*N*N insted of N*N or N*log(N). in the qsort case N*N*log(N), which still is terrible.